# Is it rigorous to hold for any intervals?

Tags: calculus, functions, uniform-convergence

I've got a confusing problem about consistent convergence in my homework:

Study the consistent convergence of the following columns of functions on the specified interval:
$f_n(x)=e^{-(x-n)^2}, I_1 = (-l, l)(l \in R^+), I_2 = (-\infty, \infty)$. It's clear that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)\equiv0$, thus $f_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $I_1$ while it doesn't remains when it comes to $I_2$.

In my opinion, this leads to a paradox that if an assignment is true for any centrosymmetric interval, then it must be true for the whole Number Axis, on the contrary to what this example shows. Are there any errors in my calculations? Or is this extension not absolutely correct?Looking forward to anyone coming to help.

This problem hit me when I was reading a proof of why the function $e^x$ has a Maclaurin Series. The author made the prove on the interval $(−R,R)$ first, as $R$ is a positive number, then made a extension to the whole number axis. What's the key reason that the same approach works for this question above? Are there any discriminatory methods that can help me determine the scope of this extension?

Comment: *if an assignment is true for any centrosymmetric interval, then it must be true for the whole Number Axis* --- Consider the following abstract situation: For each centrosymmetric interval there exists an $\epsilon > 0.$ Does it follow that there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ for the whole number axis? Not if the maximal existing $\epsilon$ for each centrosymmetric interval approaches zero as the length of the centrosymmetric interval approaches infinity.

Comment: We can't even conclude that for regular infinite integrals.  $\int_{-n}^{n}xdx=0$ but going to the whole real number line it is undefined

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for your explanation. This problem hit me when I was reading a proof of why the function $e^x$ has a Maclaurin Series. The author made the prove on the interval $(-R, R)$ first, as R is a positive number, then made a extension to the whole number axis. What's the key reason that the same approach works for this question above? Are there any discriminatory methods that can help me determine the scope of this extension?

Comment: In the case of $e^x,$ its Maclaurin series converges pointwise on $(-\infty,+\infty),$ but [not uniformly on $(-\infty,+\infty).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2094041/13130) What is true (and often used) is the fact that for each positive real number $R$ (but NOT for $R=\infty)$ the Maclaurin series for $e^x$ converges uniformly on every interval of the form $[-R,R],$ and hence also on every interval of the form $(-R,R),$ since uniform convergence on $[-R,R]$ implies uniform convergence on $(-R,R).$